# laravel view more categories

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in laravel. 
I am trying to do an e-commerce website. On the left side of the filter page (which shows products), I am going to show all the main filters and their options. But when the options are more than six I want to add a button named view more.

This is the first version without adding View More.

```
 @forelse($filters as $filter)

                      <div class="single-left-widget">
                        <div class="section-title">
                            <h4 class="text-uppercase">{{$filter->name}}</h4>
                            <ul>
                                @foreach($filter_options as $filter_option)
                                    @if($filter_option->filter_id==$filter->filter_id)
                                        <li > <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" class="filters" value="{{$filter_option->id}}"  id="{{$filter_option->id}}"  /> {{$filter_option->name}}</li>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    @empty
```

So now what I am thinking is doing a loop

```
     @forelse($filters as $filter)

                          <div class="single-left-widget">
                            <div class="section-title">
                                <h4 class="text-uppercase">{{$filter->name}}</h4>
                                <ul>

@if ($loop->count<=5)
                                    @foreach($filter_options as $filter_option)
                                        @if($filter_option->filter_id==$filter->filter_id)
                                            <li > <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" class="filters" value="{{$filter_option->id}}"  id="{{$filter_option->id}}"  /> {{$filter_option->name}}</li>
                                        @endif
                                    @endforeach


@else
View More
@endif
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @empty
```

Well, I am very confused now. Firstly, it doesn't work like this. I mean I want to click on view more and it should be shown all the filters of that category. I think I should use JS... any suggestions please of what to do?

Comment: if you want anything dynamic to happen on the page you are looking at javascript for the most part

Answer (score 0):

The below example assumes `$filters` is a Collection.

Something like this:

```php
@forelse($filters->take(5) as $filter)
    <div class="single-left-widget">
        <div class="section-title">
            <h4 class="text-uppercase">{{$filter->name}}</h4>
            <ul>
                @foreach($filter_options as $filter_option)
                    @if($filter_option->filter_id==$filter->filter_id)
                        <li > <input type="checkbox" name="cat[]" class="filters" value="{{$filter_option->id}}"  id="{{$filter_option->id}}"  /> {{$filter_option->name}}</li>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
@empty
    No Filters
@endforelse

@if ($filters->count() > 5)
    <button>View More</button>
@endif
```